# Hide map annotations but use them for notifications

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

I have this Swift code that vibrates the phone whenever a user is near a point and I have a .csv file with a lot of markers (longitudes and latitudes).
How can I hide those markers from the map but still keep the functionality of vibrating?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import AudioToolbox

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    var pointsDataSource: PointsDataSource? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupMap()
        setupData()
        setupLocationManager()
    }

    func setupMap() {
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.userTrackingMode = .follow
    }

    func setupData() {
        pointsDataSource = PointsDataSource(with: "San Francisco");

        if let pointsDataSource = pointsDataSource {
            map.addAnnotations(pointsDataSource.annotations)
        }
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        LocationManager.shared.locationUpdateCompletion = { [unowned self] location in
            if let point = self.pointsDataSource?.findPoint(near: location) {
                if !point.vibrated {
                    self.notify(about: point)
                    point.vibrated = true
                }

            }
        }

        LocationManager.shared.start()
    }

    func notify(about point: PointData) {
        print("You are near point \(point.identifier), \(point.name)")
        vibrate(3)
        show(onMap: point)
    }

    func vibrate(_ times: Int) {
        for leftToVibrate in 0..<times {
            let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5 * Double(leftToVibrate)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
            }
        }
    }

    func show(onMap point: PointData) {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: point.location.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the new user notification provisions in iOS 10.  They'll let you alert a user whether you're in the foreground or not and will be much more energy efficient.  If you're not showing the points, there's no reason to involve MapKit.

There are requirements to get user permission for the alerts - generally take a look at the documentation and / or the WWDC video.  There's also a limit on the number of points you can register, which could be an issue for you depending.

For reference, the code I'm using for this is below:

```
[In your AppDelegate to get required user authorization]

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
    { (granted, error) in

        let regionAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "regionAlert", title: "regionAlert", options: [])
        let regionCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "notify-region", actions: [regionAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([regionCategory])
    }         

[In the class where you want to use the alerts]

   private func setAlert(_ alertPosition: Position, alertTitle: String, alertSubtitle: String, alertBody: String)
   {
        unowned let myself = self
        let alertCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(alertPosition.coordinate.latitude, alertPosition.coordinate.longitude)
        let alertRegion = CLCircularRegion.init(center: alertCenter, radius: Setting.shared.alertRegionRadius, identifier: alertTitle)
        alertRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
        alertRegion.notifyOnExit = true

        content.title = "Trail*Head Alert"
        content.subtitle = alertSubtitle
        content.body = alertBody
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.categoryIdentifier = "notify-region"

        if content.badge != nil {
            content.badge = NSNumber(value: Int(content.badge!) + 1)
        } else {
            content.badge = 1
        }

        let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger.init(region: alertRegion, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: alertTitle, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request) { error in
            if (error != nil){
                print("Add Notification error: ", error!)
            }
        }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = myself
    }

    // UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate function called if app is in foreground when an alert is triggered

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) { completionHandler( [.alert,.sound]) }

    // Function to deregister any active alert regions.

    func stopAlerts()
    {
        if alertStatus {
            alertStatus = false
            center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func setupData() {
pointsDataSource = PointsDataSource(with: "San Francisco")

//if let pointsDataSource = pointsDataSource {
//map.addAnnotations(pointsDataSource.annotations)
//}
}
```